# The process of dynamic time warping

Tags: python, numpy

Hi~ I wanna do DTW and clustering. I just have a question.

```
import numpy as np

import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()

# Set up our R namespaces
R = rpy2.robjects.r
DTW = importr('dtw')

# Generate our data
idx = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
template = np.cos(idx)
query = np.sin(idx) + np.array(R.runif(100))/10

# Calculate the alignment vector and corresponding distance
alignment = R.dtw(query, template, keep=True)
dist = alignment.rx('distance')[0][0]

print(dist)
```

When I see this code, there are two time-series variables.
If I have many time-series variables(like below picture)

[image]

How can I go through the process??
I think I will set the fixed variable and compare fixed variable with other variables. like below picture

[image]

The picture means comparing A variable with whole variables.

After calculating all distance, I will do clustering method based on distance.

Is that right??

And can I choose the fixed variable arbitrarily??